# Eclipse validation barfing at my WSDL - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: xml, schema

I have a WSDL that essentially looks as follows (I hope I simplified it correctly and didn't omit anything essential):

```
 <wsdl:definitions name="foo"
                  targetNamespace="http://x.y.z"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  >
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http:/a.b.c">
            …some definitions here…
            <xsd:complexType name="bar">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="something" type="xsd:int" />
                    …more definitions here…
                <xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://e.f.g">
            …some definitions here…
            <xsd:element name="xyz" type="q1:bar" xmlns:q1="http://a.b.c" />  @@
            …more definitions here…
        </xsd:schema>
       …more definitions here…
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The Eclipse Schema validator complains on the line marked here using @@ as follows:

```
src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'q1:bar'. It was detected that 'q1:bar' is in namespace 'http:/a.b.c', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///wsdlfilename.wsdl'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'q1:bar' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///wsdlfilename.wsdl'.
```

I am almost getting a parsing exception myself reading that paragraph. ;-) What is this trying to convey to me?

The second schema obviously tries to use a type defined in the first schema and references it using its name and the targetNamespace of the first schema. 
Why is this type {http:/a.b.c}bar not referenceable in the second schema? Do I somehow need to import the first schema (or its namespace?) into the second or into the root (here "definitions") to make it accessible in the second schema? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a slash in the target namespace

`http:/a.b.c`

should be

`http://a.b.c`

People still use WSDL's huh :-)

Comment: that's just an artifact of my simplification - sorry. The real URLs are correct. - Changing my question to correct for that. And re. your question: yes - some die-hards still do! Not my favorite, but that's what we have to live with... ;-)